# Bootstrap checkbox with Canvas

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am using library https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox for adding pretty checkboxes/radiobuttons to my site and it looks well on it. But when I am trying to do a screenshot of a div block with html2canvas library, then I get some weird things on the generated [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ7uO.png) .

HTML code:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-warning checkbox-circle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" class="test-checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="checkbox5"></label>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var element = $('#body-details');
            html2canvas(element, {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL();
                    var url = $('#image-url').val();
                    $.post(url, {data: img}, function () {});
                }
            });
```

PHP code:

```
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post('data');
    $file = time() . '.jpg';
    $dirPath = './' . Yii::$app->session->get('userFolder') . '/';

    // remove "data:image/png;base64,"
    $uri =  substr($data, strpos($data, ",") + 1);

    // save to file
    if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
        mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($dirPath . '/' . $file, base64_decode($uri));
```

Maybe there are other ways how to do screenshot of the div without canvas but I did not find them.
Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: I would guess that the html2canvas library isn't perfect and isn't rendering the CSS correctly.

Comment: @alex maybe you know a good library for that? that would be helpful

Comment: `html2canvas` does "basic CSS" well, but "pretty CSS" is often unsupported. Chrome is offering a built-in screen grabber, but for the most part you can't do a screen grab for good security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There was only one solution that I found.
I have to remove bootstrap style from checkboxes before making screenshot with html2canvas. After screenshot was made and request was sent to server I set the style back. It is not so nice as it could be but I did not find any better solution.